# Limit of $x^x * e^{-x^2}$ as x tends to infinity

Tags: limits

Is there any easy way to show that $ \lim_{x\to\infty}x^x{e^{-x^2}} = 0 $ ?

We can observe that $x^x * e^{-x^2} = e^{x \ln x - x^2}$ and then it's intuitive that $x \ln x - x^2$ tends to $-\infty$ as $x \to \infty$ and therefore the original limit is zero, but I am having trouble formalizing this.

`

Comment: To prove that $x \ln(x) -x^2$ tends to $-\infty$, you can write $$x \ln(x) -x^2 = x^2 \left(\frac{\ln(x)}{x}-1 \right)$$ and use the fact that $\ln(x)/x$ tends to $0$.

Comment: Or simply $x \ln x - x^2 \le -x$ because $\ln x \le x-1$.

Comment: It is a good approach.  You have two parts, first to define $f(x)=x\ln x - x^2$ and prove $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = -\infty$. Second is to prove your original limit is the same as $\lim_{x\to \infty} e^{f(x)}=0$.  Which part gives you difficulty in formalizing?

Comment: @hardmath both :) From the existing answers, I see how to get the limit of $-\infty$. Is some general principle which would allow me to calculate the limit of the exponential? I could probably prove it from the definition of limits itself, but perhaps there is already some easier general law that would apply here?

Comment: Yes, indeed that is by the *continuity* of the exponential function "at $-\infty$".

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x) = \ln x -x$. Then $$f’ = \frac 1x -1 \lt 0 $$ for $x\gt 1$. Hence, $$ x\ln x -x^2 = xf(x) \lt xf(1) = -x \to -\infty$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:
$$x\ln x- x^2=-x^2\biggl(1-\frac{\ln x}x\biggr).$$

Comment: thanks! is there a better way to say that this converges to $-\infty$ than saying that the second term tends to one and the therefore the product will go to the limit of $-x^2$? I know the product rule for limits in general, but here one of factors doesn't have a limit (the $-x^2$ factor) so I think that rule wouldn't apply.

Comment: @bennofs: I think the simplest is to say that a the limit of a product of type $-\infty\times 1$ is $-\infty$, as this is a high-school argument. It is not an indeterminate form.